# gnuplot: 3D plot of a matrix of data

Tags: gnuplot

How can I plot (a 3D plot) a matrix in Gnuplot having such data structure,
using the first row and column as a x and y ticks (the first number of the first row is the number of columns) ?

```
4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
1 -6.20 -6.35 -6.59 -6.02
2 -6.39 -6.52 -6.31 -6.00
3 -6.36 -6.48 -6.15 -5.90
4 -5.79 -5.91 -5.87 -5.46
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly this data format can be read in with `matrix nonuniform`:

```
set view 50,20
set ticslevel 0
splot 'data.txt' matrix nonuniform with lines t ''
```

This generates the correct tics, like specified in the data file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To plot a 4D plot, using colour as the 4th dimension, you can use

```
splot  '1.txt' using 2:3:4:5  every ::1  palette
#  |                              |
#  |                              |
# used for 3d plots            skip the header line
```

Or do you want to draw a different picture, with x and y being the first column and line, and the numbers in the matrix just represinting z? Then use the following:

```
splot '1.txt' every ::1:1 matrix
```

To add some effects, you can change it to

```
set dgrid3d 4,4
splot '1.txt' every ::1:1 matrix with lines
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The last solution "set dgrid3d 4,4;
splot '1.txt' every ::1:1 matrix with lines" is good for me. Only I would like to use x ticks "0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8" and y ticks "1 2 3 4" at the base of the graph. Is it possible?

Comment: @micheletuttafesta: You can use `set xtics (0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8)`. AFAIK, gnuplot has no menas to get the numbers from the input file, so you have to generate the gnuplot script: `head -n1 input.txt | sed 's/ /,/g;s/^/set xtics(/;s/$/)/' > script.gp`.

Comment: Thanks choroba! Your suggestion is my final solution

Comment: Actually, `gnuplot` has a command to read in exactly this data format and which does also use the correct tics, see my answer.