# translate matlab plot to gnuplot 3d

Tags: matlab, 3d, gnuplot, translate

I have a matrix of fft data over time, 8192 rows of data x 600 columns of time.  The first column is a frequency label, the first row is shown below but doesn't actually exist in the data file, neither do the spaces, they are shown just for ease of reading.

```
Frequency, Sec1, Sec2, Sec3...Sec600
1e8,       -95,  -90,  -92
1.1e8,    -100, -101, -103
...
```

It is plotted in matlab with the following code  ***(Apologies to other posters, I grabbed the wrong matlab code)***

x is a matrix of 8192 rows by 600 columns, f is an array of frequency labels, FrameLength = 1, figN = 3

```
function [] = TimeFreq(x,f,FrameLength,figN)


 [t,fftSize] = size(x);
 t = (1:1:t) * FrameLength;

figure(figN);
mesh(f,t,x)
xlabel('Frequency, Hz')
ylabel('time, sec')
zlabel('Power, dBm')
title('Time-Freq Representation')
```

I cant quite figure out how to make it work in gnuplot.  Here is a sample image of what it looks like in Matlab: http://imagebin.org/253633

Comment: Hmm... the MATLAB code it for sure something else.

Comment: A more reproducible example would make it easier to help you.

Comment: There is no picture to see....

Comment: ok, image is back, for some reason it got deleted the first time around.

Comment: The MATLAB code you show creates a figure with two subplots, based on variables which we do not know where they come from. The image you posted is a single plot, with other titles and labels than those in the MATLAB script. I'm sorry, but if you want anything more substantial than "read the gnuplot manual", we need to see more than that...

Comment: @TomasLycken: That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is the gnuplot command script that I ended up using.  It has some additional elements in it that weren't in the original matlab plot but all the essentials are there.

```
set term png size 1900,1080
set datafile separator ","
set pm3d

# reverse our records so that time moves away from our perspective of the chart
set xrange[*:*] reverse

# hide parts of the chart that would make the 3d view look funny
set hidden3d

# slightly roate our perspective and compress the z axis
set view 45,75,,0.85

set palette defined (-120 "yellow", -70 "red", -30 "blue")
set grid x y z
set xlabel "time (secs)"
set ylabel "frequency"
set zlabel "dBm"

# plot all the data
set output waterfall.png
splot 'waterfall.csv' nonuniform matrix using 1:2:3 with pm3d lc palette
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in gnuplot, you'll want to take a look at the `splot` (for "surface plot") command. You can probably figure out quite a lot about it just by running the following commands in your terminal:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> help splot
```

Specifically, you want to read the help page shown by running (after the above, when the prompt asks for a subtopic): `datafile`. That should tell you enough to get you started.

Also, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750005/gnuplot-3d-plot-of-a-matrix-of-data) might be helpful.

Comment: If you need more, I got a bunch of hits that seemed reasonable on Google for "gnuplot plot 3d data file matrix" - worth a shot =)