# Gnuplot: 3d surface from discrete data

Tags: image, 3d, gnuplot, geometry-surface

i need to plot the surface of a discrete 3d function, the data is this:

```
   0.5520000      -0.3840000       0.0000001       0.0000001
   0.5520000      -0.3760000   6.5919072e-08   5.8261450e-08
   0.5520000      -0.3680000       0.0398564       0.0335707
   0.5520000      -0.3600000   2.4211279e-08   2.6520126e-08
   0.5520000      -0.3520000       0.0000002       0.0000002
   0.5520000      -0.3440000       0.1945450       0.1962598
   0.5520000      -0.3360000       0.0794571       0.0792212
   0.5520000      -0.3280000   1.3106068e-08   1.6226917e-08
   0.5520000      -0.3200000       0.3029487       0.3209866
   0.5520000      -0.3120000       0.2192498       0.2272512
   0.5520000      -0.3040000       0.2904586       0.3077338
   0.5520000      -0.2960000       0.2505561       0.2639075
```

...

and i want to plot the 1:2:3 columns. I try to use the simple gnuplot command:

```
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

but i receive the following warning message:

```
Warning: Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.
       Hint: Missing blank lines in the data file? See 'help pm3d' and FAQ.
```

And the output is an empty 3d plot.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the warning message tells you: you are missing blank lines in your file. For use with `pm3d`, the data must be organized as follows:

```
x0 y0 z00
x0 y1 z01
....
x0 yN z0N

x1 y0 z10
x1 y1 z11
...
x1 yN z1N
```

etc. You must have a single blank line between consecutive x values.

Comment: It must be time-consuming and tedious when you have to organize raw data in this way before you can use GNU's 3D plot ? Any recommendations how to organize efficiently raw data to match the splot-option in GNU?

Comment: Why should that be tedious? Usually you have some program which generates your data and it is quite straightforward to map an array to this format. And gnuplot (not GNU!) supports also other file formats, see `matrix` and `matrix nonuniform` ([gnuplot: 3D plot of a matrix of data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12750005/2604213)) in the docs. And you can read in binary arrays, or use a binary format like `hdf5` to save your arrays and `h5totxt` to extract them in a suitable format. Much of the recommendations depend you your data amount, data source and grid format (uniform or not).

Answer (score 1):

The following will take an input file of more that 2 columns, sort it and add an empty line whenever the first column changes, i.e. what Gnuplot requires:

```
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -n infile.txt | \
awk 'BEGIN{pr=0}{if(NR>1){if($1!=pr){print ""}} pr=$1;print $0}' >outfile.txt
```

Explanation:

numerically (`-n`) sort your input first with respect to the first column (`-k 1,1`), then to the second (`-k 2,2`) and will pipe the result to awk which will add a newline if the previous line's first field is not the same as the current one's.