# gnuplot: time course plot of a matrix of data

Tags: gnuplot

I have Matrix Data like: 
[gnuplot: 3D plot of a matrix of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750005/gnuplot-3d-plot-of-a-matrix-of-data)

How can I plot a 2D time course of parts of the data. E.g. in the example the time course for the value 0.6 would be: -6.35, -6.52, -6.48, -5.91.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have column data and you want to plot the values on one of them, column 3 in the example you give. In `gnuplot` this is achieved with `using`:

```
plot "data" using 0:3 every ::1
```

`using 0:3` means "plot the values in column `0` as the x value and those in column `3` as the y value". Column 0 in `gnuplot` gives the order in which the data element appears (that is, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...).

`every ::1` means start by plotting item number `1` (the first item would be number `0` in `gnuplot`). In your example this prevents `0.6` to be plotted together with the other elements in the column, `-6.35`, `-6.52`, `-6.48`, `-5.91`.

Typing `help using` and `help every` within `gnuplot` will give you more detailed info.

Comment: I also thought about this "using" but it doesn't work -> empty plot with wrong x-Range (should be first column). How would I access the next column (0.7; -6.35, -6.52...)? Definitely not with 0:4.

Comment: @user3624797 You must have some other problem going on, the code I posted works fine for me with the data from the example.

Comment: 3D Plot works fine. Correct X- and Y-Axes. Correct data.

Comment: @user3624797 Can you post the exact full code you are using to plot this?