# 3D graph using matrix nonuniform structure with date/time

Tags: date, time, 3d, gnuplot

I have a data in a matrix nonuniform structure like in this post:
[gnuplot: 3D plot of a matrix of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750005/gnuplot-3d-plot-of-a-matrix-of-data)

The first row is for x ticks and the first column is for y ticks.

```
4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
25.8.2014 20:56:10 -6.20 -6.35 -6.59 -6.02
25.8.2014 20:56:20 -6.39 -6.52 -6.31 -6.00
25.8.2014 20:56:30 -6.36 -6.48 -6.15 -5.90
25.8.2014 20:56:40 -5.79 -5.91 -5.87 -5.46
```

How do I plot a 3D graph using Gnuplot with date/time on an axis using data in matrix nonuniform structure?

```
set terminal svg size 400,300 enhanced fname 'arial'  fsize 10 butt solid
set output 'out.svg'
set view 50,20
set ticslevel 0
set ydata time
set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format y "%d/%m %H:%M"
splot 'data.txt' matrix nonuniform with lines t ''
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot use the `nonuniform` matrix input with time data. I played around with your data and looked a bit through the source code of the data routine. Maybe there is some workaround (with some external tools to convert your data file), but if you have the choice, I would recommend you to change the data format.