# Print a matrix in a text file

Tags: c++, gnuplot, fstream

I want to plot a 3D plot (x,y,z) with gnuplot.

In order to do so I thought of writing a matrix to a textfile using fstream in C++ and then according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750005/gnuplot-3d-plot-of-a-matrix-of-data) get the 3D plot of a matrix of data using splot.

Assuming that this is the right way to do that the data inside the text file should look like this:

```
       x[1]    x[2]      x[3] 
y[1] z[1][1]  z[1][2]   z[1][2]
y[2] z[2][1]  z[1][2]   z[2][3]
y[3] z[3][1]  z[3][2]   z[3][3]
```

In order to get the matrix I wrote the following code:

```
fstream myfile;
myfile.open("example.txt",fstream::out);

//rows
for (int j=0; j< 3;j++)
{
  myfile << x[j]<< std::endl;
}

//columns
for (int i=0; i< 3;i++)
{
  myfile << y[i]<< std::endl;
}

//columns
for (int i=1; i< 3;i++)
{
  //rows
  for (int j=1; j< 3;j++)
  {
    myfile << z[i][j] << std::endl;
  }
}

myfile.close();
```

I get everything in a column this way, so the question is how can I print a matrix?

Comment: You really need better [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Comment: Do you realise that indexes in C++ start with 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, (I'm assuming you need tabs between each element of the matrix, input commas if desired)

```
fstream myfile;

myfile.open("example.txt",fstream::out);

for (int j=0; j< 3;j++)// Prints row of x
{        
    myfile << x[j]<< "\t";  
}

myfile<< std::endl;

for (int i=0; i< 3;i++) //This variable is for each row below the x 
{        
    myfile << y[i]<< "\t";

    for (int j=0; j<3;j++)
    {                      
        myfile << z[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    myfile<<std::endl;
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Thank you..z[0][0] is empty. That is why I wrote three loops.

Comment: Do you mean to say your indexing starts from z[1][1] and x[1] and y[1]? Because in C++ they start from 0

Comment: z[1][1] but x[0] and y[0]. I have shown the matrix in the question above. So I guess "\t" is what I have been missing. So is there a way to have an empty slot?

Comment: What do you mean by an empty slot? If you mean z[0][0] is 0, just output it regularly and it will show up as zero

Comment: I tried your script, I still get z[i][j] in a column. x[j] is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, your loops aren't very well defined and you should know that std::endl jumps to a new line that's why you're getting 1 column.
try :

```
for (int j=0; j< 3;j++){
    myfile << x[j] <<"\t";  
}

myfile<< std::endl;

for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++){
    myfile << y[j]<<"\t";
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        myfile << z[j]x[i]<<"\t";
    myfile<< std::endl;
}
```