# how to manage xtics,ytics from matrix data file when changing orientation

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a big file of matrix organized data (200 rows by 6000 columns in the file).
Data is the output of an FFT on radio signal across 18 to 24 MHz, 6000 bins of 1KHz each.
The file contains also header information for rows and columns: 1 top row with the list of the 6000 frequencies and one date-time at start of each row for the acquisition timestamp.
The resulting plot is the following:
[image]

obtained in gnuplot with these statements:

```
set datafile separator ","
set ticslevel 0
plot 'test3.mat' matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:3 with image
```

For my planned usage I need to have it horizontally oriented like the following, but only the data gets rotated while all rows and columns tics are now on the wrong axis.
[image]

data rotation obtained changing the plot statement in this way:

```
plot 'test3.mat' matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 2:1:3 with image
```

Is there a way to:

- "rotate" also the tics to have them on the correct axis (frequencies on y and time on x)
- and reduce the number of tics used on the chart to avoid the ugly overlap of text

**Additional tests did using info from the comments:**

**TEST 1**
with this one I see the tics but NO heatmap at all (+ this msg: "*warning: Image grid must be at least 2 x 2*" )

```
plot 'test3.mat' matrix nonuniform using 2:1:3 with image
```

[image]

**TEST 2**
with new file (no header/timestamps) i almost get the desired result. The x axis is still wrong and i would like an easier way to produce the tics values.

```
set datafile separator ","
set ticslevel 0

set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M:%S"

set format y "%.1s"

set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix

plot 'test3-nohead.mat' matrix using ("2015-12-03 15:08:39"+0.05*$2):(18000000.0+1000.0*$1):3 with image
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to read out the row and column headers as strings? If the time steps are equidistant you could try gnuplot's `matrix nonuniform` format, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12750005/2604213 Otherwise you might need to change your format completly

Comment: no specific need actually, the file was produced in human readable format. 

With this command I see the tics but NO heatmap at all (+ this msg: "warning: Image grid must be at least 2 x 2" )

plot 'test3.mat' matrix nonuniform using 2:1:3 with image

Comment: about changing the format completely: I produced a new version of the file without header/timestamps. It now has just the data matrix.
I had to edit the using clause to see the expected tics values. please see above the updated question with new image and gnuplot statements. Do you have any hints about generating correct values also for the x axis (time) ?

Comment: @Christoph Hi and thank you for your hint. I'm still having big issues with the X axis. I just see minutes and seconds, and they don't seem to be the values I'm trying to obtain with using on the plot statement. The Y axis and the heatmap are perfect now. Do you have further suggestions ? Thank you, Mario

Comment: I had seen your additions, but no time to answer :) Regarding your approach with `matrix nonuniform`: make sure you have the correct format, the first line must contain the number of columns as first entry: `N x0 x1 ... xN-1`. Maybe that is the actual problem here. Regarding the other approach, use `timecolumn` and `strptime` to handle time data, search for those functions here on SO.

Comment: Thank you! Seems that strptime solved the last issue on the x axis. If you want to enter some text in the answer or referring to your comments, i will mark that as the answer. Thanks again, Mario

Comment: Ps: i will update asap the question with latest version of the code and output